# How can I uninstall wine from Ubuntu?

Tags: winetricks, software-uninstall

How do I completely remove winetricks from my Ubuntu OS? I have tried `sudo apt-get --purge remove wine` but when I click on the windows button it still shows the application of configure wine.

Comment: Winetricks got removed but its still showing the application of configure wine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wine and winetricks are two separate packages.
To remove both wine and winetricks and all dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine winetricks
sudo apt-get autoremove
```